# Text is going below the page bottom

Tags: page-breaking, ieeetran

I am writing a LaTeX document using the `IEEEtran` document class. But the problem is the text is going beyond the page bottom. That is, the text in the column 1 is getting truncated by the lower bottom of the page. Is there some way that this problem can be handled?

This is how my document structure goes:

```
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTbaselinestretch}{1}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTinnersidemargin}{1in} 
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTtoptextmargin}{1in}
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\title{MyTitle}
\maketitle

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{myBib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 6):

Move `\maketitle` to *after* `\begin{document}`. You need to place any contents that is actually typeset within the `document` environment.